# How to change color of button based on row value

Tags: php, html

This code disables the button if the row's value is not 0.
Now I want to change its color also to red if its not 0.

```
 <button type="button" value="4" 
 class="seat btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="change4()"
 <?php echo $row->Seat4 === "0" ? "" : "disabled";  ?>> 04 </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add background color also in style while you comparing value

```
<button type="button" value="4" class="seat btn btn-sm btn-success" 
onclick="change4()"
<?php echo $row->Seat4 === "0" ? "" : "disabled style='background-color : red'";  ?> 
> 04 </button>
```

**EDIT**

```
<button type="button" value="4" class="seat btn btn-sm <?php echo $row->Seat4 === "0" ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger";  ?>" 
    onclick="change4()"
<?php echo $row->Seat4 === "0" ? "" : "disabled";  ?>  > 04 </button>
```

Comment: thanks bro. .how  about changing the class to btn-danger if the value is not 0.

Comment: make a condition inside the button class  and echo the class name ``btn-danger`` if it is true echo ``btn-success`` and else echo ``btn-danger``